# What is the type of apomorphism specific to list and how is it implemented?

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes, unfold

I am learning recursion schemes and it has proven very helpful to me to implement them specific to the list type. However, I got stuck on apomorphisms.

Here is an implementation of `tails` in terms of apo I recently found:

```hs
import Data.Functor.Foldable

tailsApo :: [a] -> [[a]]
tailsApo = apo coalgTails
    where
    coalgTails = \case
        [] -> Cons [] (Left [])
        li@(_:xs) -> Cons li (Right xs)
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't import `Data.Functor.Foldable` with GHCi, because I get a package not found error. Another search revealed this implemenation of apo specific to lists:

```hs
apoList :: ([b] -> Maybe (a, Either [b] [a])) -> [b] -> [a]
apoList f b = case f b of
    Nothing -> []
    Just (x, Left c)  -> x : apoL f c
    Just (x, Right e) -> x : e
```

Obviously, `apoList`'s first argument doesn't match with `tailsApo`. I'd expext the type to be something like `apoList :: ([b] -> Either (a, b) [a])) -> [b] -> [a]`.

There seems to be no more beginner friendly information on this subject. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You can install the package with `cabal install recursion-schemes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data.Functor.Foldable` is provided by the *recursion-schemes* package. The type of [`apo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.1.3/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:apo) there is:

```
apo :: Corecursive t => (a -> Base t (Either t a)) -> a -> t
```

Here, `t` is the structure being generated by the unfold, and `Base t` is its base functor. Broadly speaking, the base functor represents one level of the recursive structure, the idea being that if we indefinitely nest it within itself we get a type equivalent to that of the whole structure -- in fact, that is precisely what `Fix` from `Data.Functor.Foldable` does. (On a meta note, there doesn't seem to be a Q&A here specifically about `Base` in *recursion-schemes*; it could be useful to have one.)

`Base` for lists is:

```
data ListF a b = Nil | Cons a b
```

So `apo` specialises to:

```
apo @[_] :: (b -> ListF a (Either [a] b)) -> b -> [a]
```

If we want to write it without using the *recursion-scheme* infrastructure, we can use the fact that `ListF a b` is isomorphic to `Maybe (a, b)`:

```
Nil     | Cons  a  b
Nothing | Just (a, b)
```

In terms of `Maybe (a, b)`, the signature would then become:

```
apoList :: (b -> Maybe (a, Either [a] b)) -> b -> [a]
```

In the coalgebra (that is, the function argument to `apo`), `Nothing` (or `Nil`, in the *recursion-schemes* version) signal the generation of the list should be stopped by capping it with an empty tail. That is why you still need `Maybe`, even if you are also using `Either` to short-circuit the unfold in other ways.

The implementation of this `apoList` is pretty much like the one in your question, except that this signature doesn't restrict the seed (of `b` type) to a list, and flips the roles of `Left` and `Right` (so that `Left` signals short-circuiting):

```
apoList :: (b -> Maybe (a, Either [a] b)) -> b -> [a]
apoList f b = case f b of
    Nothing -> []
    Just (x, Left e) -> x : e
    Just (x, Right c) -> x : apoList f c
```

Answer (score 1):

[The type is](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.1.3/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:apo)

```
apo :: (a ->           Base t   (Either t  a  ))      -- g :: a -> Base t r
    ->  a -> t 

apo  g  a =  rec a  where                             -- rec = apo g :: a -> t
             rec = embed . fmap (either id rec) . g  
{-
type family                           Base t :: * -> * 
embed                ::               Base t    t -> t
fmap (either id rec) :: Base t   r -> Base t    t
      either id rec  ::          r ->           t            r ~ Either t a
          g :: a ->     Base t   r                           r ~ Either t a
rec = apo g :: a ->                                  t
-}
```

Here `a` is the seed. For `t ~ [b]` [we'll have](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.1.3/docs/src/Data.Functor.Foldable.html#line-325)

```
type instance Base [b] = ListF b
data                     ListF b r = Nil | Cons b r

Base t (Either t a) ~    ListF b (Either [b] a) 
                    ~                Maybe     (b, Either [b] a)
```

so overall it'll be

```
apoList :: (a -> Maybe (b, Either [b] a)) -> a -> [b] 
apoList coalg a = case coalg a of
   Nothing           -> []  -- (embed  Nil       )                       -- either
   Just (b, Left bs) -> b : bs   -- no more seed, no more steps to do!   --   id    $ bs
   Just (b, Right a) -> b : apoList coalg a  -- new seed, go on!         --   apo g $ a
                     -- ^^^^^  (embed (Cons b bs))
```

so

```
apoTails :: [a] -> [[a]]      -- [[a]] ~ [b], b ~ [a]
apoTails = apoList tailsCoalg
  where
  -- tailsCoalg :: [a] -> Maybe ([a], Either [[a]] [a])
  tailsCoalg []       = Just ([], Left [])
  tailsCoalg s@(_:xs) = Just (s, Right xs)
```

---

*edit:* a simpler `apoList` with a simpler typed coalgebra,

```
apoListE :: (a -> Either [b] (b, a)) -> a -> [b] 
apoListE coalg a = case coalg a of
   Left bs      -> bs             -- final tail, whether empty or non-empty 
   Right (b, a) -> b : apoListE coalg a     -- new element and seed, go on!
```

seems to be easier to use:

```
apoTailsE :: [a] -> [[a]]
apoTailsE = apoListE tailsCoalgE
  where
  -- tailsCoalgE :: [a] -> Either [[a]] ([a], [a])
  tailsCoalgE []       = Left [[]]
  tailsCoalgE s@(_:xs) = Right (s, xs)
```

Looks like the two types are equivalent:

```
type instance Base [b] = ListF b
data                     ListF b r = Nil | Cons b r

Base t (Either t a) ~    ListF b (Either [b] a) 
                    ~                Maybe     (b, Either [b] a)
                    ~                              Either [b] (b, a)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Maybe (b, Either [b] a)  ~  Either [b] (b, a) 

{ Nothing,               ~  { Left [], 
  Just (b, Left bs),          Left (b:bs), 
  Just (b, Right a)           Right (b, a)
}                           }
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `s@(_:xs)`?

Comment: it is called "as-pattern". `s` refers to the whole, and is simultaneously matched up with `(_:xs)`.

Comment: Both answers are very helpful and I wish I could accept both in a kind of shared mode. Acceptance shouldn't be binary on SO in some cases.